# What is a "Scripted Getter" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, properties

I was reading [Know Your Engines - How to Make Your JavaScript Fast (pdf)](http://people.mozilla.com/~dmandelin/KnowYourEngines_Velocity2011.pdf) today and ran accross this JavaScript code on Slide #25 **Properties in the Slow Zone**.

```
// "Scripted Getter"
var a = { x: get() { return 1; } };
```

This is a Parse Error in Safari 5.0.5.

Can anyone guess what a "scripted getter" is in JavaScript?

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters) although the syntax is slightly different. Maybe an error in the slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what implementation your syntax is supposed to work on. The paper claims it's "fast on IE" so it may be an IE-specific syntax.

There is an ECMAScript 5 feature where the syntax is:

```
var a = { get x() { return 1; } };
```

And there was an older Mozilla feature where the syntax is:

```
a.__defineGetter__("x",function () { return 1; });
```

The idea is supposed to be when you access a.x it will run the function and give you the value it returns. When you *write to* the x property, it will run a function defined as a setter in the same manner.

Comment: I think you're right that it's a typo. My Safari simply doesn't support the ECMA syntax, but it works fine in Firefox 4.0.1.